# Is there a more precise phrase for "can and should?"

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

The idea that one is able and obligated to act is often conveyed through the phrase, "can and should." Is there a way to convey the same idea through a single word or is there a stronger way to combine the verb can with an auxiliary verb?

Comment: 'One can and should check to see if there have been other questions on the subject of compound adjectives.' could be written more emphatically 'One can check to see if there have been other questions on the subject of compound adjectives. One _should_ check to see if there have been other questions on the subject of compound adjectives.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In moral philosophy there is the concept "ought implies can" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ought_implies_can). In other words, you have no moral obligation to do something which you are not capable of doing.

So the "can" in "can and should" is in this sense redundant, and you could just say "should" by itself.

Comment: What about Have to? Doesn't it convey both the meaning of ability and obligation?

Comment: Alas, neither The World As It Is nor Great Mother English is impressed by the theories of moral philosophers.

Comment: It seems the Strunk and White answer is to drop the redundant "can."

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "can and should" conveys the idea that the action is acceptable, and expected.  "must" could be substituted for should to give a bit more obligation to the imperative, and the "can and" could be left off to give even more indication that the action is not optional.  Otherwise, go to direct imperatives like it is required to do the action.

Answer (score 1):

*Shall* works as well.  It creates both aspects of "should" and "can."  "Shall" encompasses an intention that is obliged, much like "should,"  It also adds the definiteness that the thing will be done, ergo the "can" is necessarily implied.  One shall only do something if one can.

Answer (score 0):

**the onus must be on** (you who/those who/those that) (has/have) the capability

[MacMillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/onus)

> if the onus is on someone to do something, it is their responsibility or duty to do it

[finedictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/onus.html)

[image]